# How to create a custom sharepoint login/logout button for windows authentication?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

How to create a custom sharepoint login/logout button for windows authentication? I need to get the default sharepoint login popup when the login button is clicked.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you would need to tweak original login forms.

- For the logout is simple just call the proper page in the _layouts
  folder "/_layouts/signout.aspx" (Site collection relative!)
- For the login, one approach is again to redirect to the proper page
  as explain here, in the bottom of the article
  (http://kalashnikovtechnoblogs.blogspot.ch/2011/08/custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.html)